# $('#tipo').val('juridica');

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Pessoal estou com um grande problema na recepção e envio dos dados para o banco de dados pois, ao criar um sistema onde existe a possibilidade de utilizarmos a pessoa fisica ou a pessoa juridica, elas enviam para a mesma pagina php utilizando o modo get posso mostrar melhor como fica (sempre utilizo o mothod post)..

```
localhost/php/action_cadastro.php?tipo=fisica&txtNome=elizandro+rafael+schmidt&txtEndereco=sanntos+dumont&txtBairro=lolo&txtCidade=louco&txtUf=SC&txtCep=02210-202&txtEmail=elizandro159%40gmail.com&txtTelefone=%2802%29+9390-3000&txtCelular=&txtRazaoSocial=&txtCnpj=&txtNomeFantasia=&txtEndereco2=&txtBairro2=&txtCidade2=&txtUf2=SC&txtCep2=&txtEmail2=&txtTelefone2=&txtFax2=&txtCelular2=&txtSite=&login=&senha=&senha2=
```

**

Mas o problema é que não sei como criar a condição onde eu possa ler o tipo fisica ou juridica, tentei dessa forma:

```
$tipo= $_post['tipo'];
if($tipo==="juridica"){ tantmatnantant
}else{
if($tipo==="fisica"){blablablablabla
}
```

mas ao armazenar dessa forma ela vai nula ao banco de dados, que esta corretamente conectado levando todas as variaveis do fisica. (detalhe utilizei a mesma tabela para evitar incomodo no login)

```
   $query = " INTO usuario (tipo,Nome,Endereco,Bairro,Cidade,Uf,Cep,Email,Telefone,Celular,Razao,Cnpj,Fantasia,Endereco2,Bairro2,Cidade2,Uf2,Cep2,Email2,Tel2,Fax2,Celular2,site,login,senha,data,hora)
         VALUES ('$tipo','$Nome','$Endereco','$Bairro','$Cidade','$Uf','$Cep','$Email','$Telefone','$Celular','$Razao','$Cnpj','$Fantasia','$Endereco2','$Bairro2','$Cidade2','$Uf2','$Cep2','$Email2','$Tel2','$Fax2','$Celular2','$site','$login','$senha','$data','$hora')"or die ("1337");
          $insert = mysql_query ($query,$conexao);
```

---

Comment: Mas use o método POST, e faça a separação, if($_POST[tipo_pessoa]==fisica) $tp = fisica else $tp = juridica..

Comment: Sempre utilizo o método post apenas para mostra utilizei o get, mas irei tentar amigo, vamos ver se funcionara.
Já respondo se consegui.

Comment: Ok, sem problemas, só avisar.

Comment: Não funcionou amigo... @.@ (Não estou conseguindo me tocar em qual é o erro @.@ )kkk

Comment: Deixei uma resposta que pode resolver seu problema :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu exemplo você usa o método GET para submeter o formulário e pega o retorno com POST. Quando submeter o formulário usando GET pegue o retorno com `$_GET`, se mandar usando POST pegue o retorno com $_POST.

**Note que a variável do php $_POST é case sensitive**, então $_POST é diferente de $_post. No seu código você utiliza os dois casos. Mude todos para `$_POST` (maiúscula).

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: Obrigado amigo voce me ajudou ...  bom já havia superado esse problema mas, agradeço muito pois, dificilmente iria perceber esse erro sozinho...

Comment: :) Valeu! O problema era esse mesmo?

Comment: sim amigo, era um as ultimas variaveis _post que introduzi no codigo , não verificando ligamento do capslock...
obrigado pela ajuda..